# What is a method to create an jigsaw puzzled sphere in Blender?

Tags: python, blender, modeling

I'm just a newbie in Blender.

Going to create an jigsaw puzzled sphere model, like wikipedia one, or these plastic 3D puzzles you have probably saw.

[image: puzzled globe]

For now, i have created Python script which creates arbitrary plain 2D puzzles with Bezier curves, which later can be easy be converted to a mesh

[image: curved puzzle]

But how to wrap it around a sphere ?

PS. Just had an idea -
to unwrap cube on the puzzle plane, copy edges as negative as shown below

[image: unwrapped cube]

(there no copy of edges on the picture yet).
Then with affine transformations, transform each 2D cube face to respective 3D place, and then apply Object->Transform->To Sphere modifier.

What do you think ? Is there a better way to create puzzled sphere ?
Thanks for your attention !

EDIT: You know, there is a dodecahedron, which can be also assembled from pentagon faces

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053/935) shows an easy way to turn a plane into a sphere. It is easy to [create modifiers with python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61949/935).

Comment: @sambler Nice solution, however its not suitable for me - see the pole faces are collapsed, but all puzzle pieces have to be relatively same size. Actually i'm going to print this model in metal :)

Answer (score 3):

Transformed code to blender add-on
https://bitbucket.org/ios29A/blender_puzzle_generator, maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 2):

Actually 30Kb of Python code, and cube faces are transformed by hands
[image: sample]

Just finished it with affine transformations of cube faces.
See a heart from 7x7x7 cube, so here is plain->cube->sphere->lattice transform

[image: heart from plain->cube->sphere->lattice]

I think this method makes it possible to create any 3D shape from squares, even not sphere ones.

Was going to print it in plastic before metal.
Here it is 3х3х3 and was made right before 14' February
[image: Plastic heart]
[image: Plastic heart]

Comment: To aid future readers, you should include details on how you solved your problem.  For example, what is the code you refer to?

Comment: @PeterO.Well its not solved, i think there should be a better way, for now i just copy edges as shown in image above. The code i refer to is made by myself and its not published yet, just going to make it as add-on for Blender to generate 2D & 3D puzzles cubes with all sizes specified and many options

Comment: @PeterO.Long time, but here it is https://bitbucket.org/ios29A/blender_puzzle_generator

Answer (score -1):

It's much simpler than you may imagine.

1. Download the addon from the given link above (https://bitbucket.org/ios29A/blender_puzzle_generator).
2. Install it (refer to the documentation).
3. In Blender, create a cuboid puzzle (add-curve-puzzle. Choose cuboid in the shape option).
4. Convert the curve into a mesh (object-convert to-mesh...)
5. Select the cuboid and enter edit mode (tab)
6. Select all (A)
7. Mesh-transform-to sphere.
8. Move your mouse.

Comment: You know, this is mine solution described in this question. However, i think its not the best. Where you've found it ? Thanks